# NSCache to store images for UITableView In Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nscache

I'm new in swift programming  and I have searched a lot about storing images with NSCache using Swift.

What I have done so far is that I'm getting `id`s and `imageName`s with JSON and I have my data in array and I was able to display image in cells with no problem. Now I want to cache images.
This is the code that I have written:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

        //cell.imageView
         nameID = self.hoge[indexPath.row]["cars"]["carid"].string!
        cell.nameLabel.text = nameID

        if let imageFileURL = imageCache.objectForKey(self.hoge[indexPath.row]["cars"]["carid"].intValue) as? NSURL {
            println("Get image from cache")

        } else {

            imageName = self.hoge[indexPath.row]["cars"]["pic_name"].string!

            // If the image does not exist, we need to download it
            var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.35/car/uploads/" + imageName )!

            var image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "pen")!
            // Download an NSData representation of the image at the URL
            let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    image = UIImage(data: data)!
                    cell.viewCell.image = image

                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })

        }

        return cell
    }
```

SO, How can I store and retrieve images with cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to check this library [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) (It provides a memory and LRU disk cache for UIImage, NSData, JSON, String or any other type that can be read or written as data), at least to understand how they are dealing with cache, and you can decide to use it or create your own solution.

Using a very easy/simple API:

```
// Setting a remote image
imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)

// Setting an image manually. Requires you to provide a key.
imageView.hnk_setImage(image, key: key)
```

Using the cache

```
let cache = Shared.dataCache

cache.set(value: data, key: "image.png")

// Eventually...

cache.fetch(key: "image.png").onSuccess { data in
     // Do something with data
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution . But I notice that For installation I have to include the whole project , Isn't that going to decrease the performance of my app ?

Comment: What If I don't use this framework?What's the solution?

Comment: You just need to include the correspondent library in your project, will not decrease the performance. If you don't want to use this framework, you can try what I suggested, study some techniques they are using and implement something that suits you better.

Comment: Thanks ,I just found one way of installation that said Drag `Haneke.xcodeproj` to your project in the _Project Navigator . What's the other way so I don't have to include the whole project into my app?

Comment: Create a folder called libraries (or any name you want) and drag only files related to the library (not tests, xibs, etc). You can see in this folder, all what is necessary: https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift/tree/master/Haneke

Comment: Could you give me an example which first check if data is cached ,If so return that data otherwise get if from network ? It's quite confusing for me .Thank you very much