# How to use NSCache and download Image From Url and Show images in CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, download, nscache

I have a UICollectionViewCell and Inside that there is a imageView. My requirement is that I am getting Images Url from My_API and I want to download the Images from these Images Url and want to show them into a collectionViewCell imageView.

First thing is that how can I download the images from url I mean Which method is best and how to use NSCache in CollectionViewCell for images (in CellForRowAtIndexPath method).

Here is my code:

//MARK : DataSource

```
extension BrandImagesTableCell : UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if 0 != arrImages.count {
        return self.arrImages.count
    }

    return 0
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BrandImagesCell", for: indexPath) as! BrandImagesCell

    //let StrUrl = NSURL(string: self.arrImages[indexPath.row])! as URL
    let urlPath: String = self.arrImages[indexPath.row]
    let StrUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    if 0 != arrImages.count
    {
        cell.brandImage.downloadedFrom(url: StrUrl as URL)//, contentMode: .scaleToFill)
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    return cell
 }
}
```

In self.arrImages I have Images url.

And here is my download image method:

//Download Image from server.

```
extension UIImageView {
 func downloadedFrom(url: URL) { //, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    //contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
  }
}
```

So I want to know which method is better to download images, and do I have to use thread or NSCache?

Comment: you should use sd_webimageview for download image and set it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSCache to store images for UITableView In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004336/nscache-to-store-images-for-uitableview-in-swift)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya sd_weimageview is an Obj-C library, it works fine with Swift but I prefer to use a library that built in Swift, such as [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

Comment: ya sorry . kingfisher for download image for swift 2.0

Comment: Kingfisher Library? But without adding Library is there any method?

Comment: HanekeSwift (https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) works for Swift 2.3

Comment: For downloading images ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. The library downloads and caches them.

Comment: Can any one please explain me in my code what to do?
I mean I don't want to integrate any library to download images.
Thanks

Comment: did you want kingfisher example ?

Comment: I also want to know that which one is better among Alamofire, SD_WebIMage,KingFisher ,Haneke ?
I mean efficiency wise or performance .
Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 i just you only 3 that are alamofire , SD_webImage and kingfisher and i suggest you for swift kingfisher .

Answer (score 0):

Use [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) download this library and add into your project.

**Use code like :**

```
let ProfileUrl = YOUR_URL! as! String
if ProfileUrl.isEmpty == true {
        YOURIMAGE_VIEW.image = UIImage.init(named: "ic_default_IMAGE.png")
}else{
        let fbUrl = NSURL(string: ProfileUrl )!
         YOURIMAGE_VIEW.kf_setImageWithURL(fbUrl, placeholderImage: nil,
                                        optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(1))],
                                        progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in

            },
            completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                                            print("Finished")
        })

    }
```

**Retrive image from cache file**

```
KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(url, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
    print(image)
})
```

Comment: It Would better if you can explain me in my  'question'  code only 
Thanks.

Comment: @kishor0011 when you got response from url then store in one array and after it just pass value of url in your url that i mention in answer and its automatically set in imageview when your image download from server .

Comment: OK Let me try this.
Cache will also work in this library right?
Thanks

Comment: ya kingfisher is best in swift . for download image . if any problem then read document .

Comment: Ok 
I will read documents first and then I will implement it.
Thanks

Comment: I read the documentation .
Its good only.
Once I will try this and will let you know.
Thanks

Comment: Here how can I get that cache image and downloading ?
Thanks

Comment: optionsInfo option type check it in libaray

Comment: KingfisherManager.sharedManager.retrieveImageWithURL(url, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
    print(image)
})

Comment: Oh ok I will check it.

Comment: OK Now In my question how can I do it.?
Thanks

Comment: in your question i m not see any array that you store your url that you get from server or api . so when you got it then just simply pass array url value to YOUR_URL as string and then its automatically handle all thing.

Comment: See in My question arrImages is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132692/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-kishor0011).

Comment: Where to write this method second one you just written. Thanks

Comment: @kishor0011 if your problem solve now then approve my answer . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 3 :-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BrandImagesCell", for: indexPath) as! BrandImagesCell

    //let StrUrl = NSURL(string: self.arrImages[indexPath.row])! as URL
    let urlPath: String = self.arrImages[indexPath.row]
    //let StrUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    if 0 != arrImages.count
    {
        let imgUrl = urlPath

        //Add Default image
        if imgUrl.isEmpty == true {
            cell.brandImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "placeholder.png")
        }

        else
        {
            let url = URL(string: imgUrl)!
             cell.brandImage.kf.setImage(with: url,
                                  placeholder: nil,
                                  options: [.transition(.fade(0.5))],
                                  progressBlock: { receivedSize, totalSize in
                                  print("\(indexPath.row + 1): \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
                                },

                                  completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
                                    print("Finished")
                                    //print("\(indexPath.row + 1): Finished")
                                })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```